# Golang signal handling and time.Sleep() interactions

Tags: go, signals, sleep

I'm having trouble with a Go program that is supposed to be catching SIGTERM and gracefully shutting down. I can see that it starts the shutdown procedure, but then it just suddenly exits without completing the shutdown procedure. I've placed some logging in various places and can see that they're not printing anything to stdout. Here's a code snippet and results:

```
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    select {
    case <-sigs:
        signal.Stop(sigs)
        log.Info().Msg("runsomething: SIGTERM caught")
        close(stopC)
        cancel()
        log.Info().Msg("Stopping all goroutines")

        // This sleep doesn't have any effect when shutdown via SIGTERM
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        log.Info().Msg("THIS SHOULD PRINT, WHY DOESNT IT?")
    case <-doneC:
    }

    // This sleep doesn't have any effect when shutdown via SIGTERM nor
    // does the following log print
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
    log.Info().Msg("runsomething: DONE")
```

Here's the result to normal completion:

```
./runsomething             
May  5 09:46:35.000 INF runsomething started 
May  5 09:46:37.000 INF Summarizing results and exiting
May  5 09:46:37.000 INF Run results COMPLETED
May  5 09:46:39.000INF runsomething: DONE
```

Here are the results with an interrupt:

```
May  5 09:39:48.000 INF runsomething started
^CMay  5 09:39:50.000 INF runsomething: SIGTERM caught
May  5 09:39:50.000 INF Stopping all goroutines
May  5 09:39:50.000 INF GracefulShutdown: Started
```

There are several missing output lines. Given the code snippet above I expected to see:

```
...continued from above...
May  5 09:39:50.000 INF THIS SHOULD PRINT, WHY DOESNT IT? The sleep below also isn't run?
May  5 09:39:50.000 INF GracefulShutdown: Completed
May  5 09:39:50.000 INF runsomething: DONE
```

The `time.Sleep()` calls don't appear to work. After the initial log stating `GracefulShutdown: Started` there is no pause before the program silently exits. I tried reproducing the problem with a much smaller example that mimics the code above, but it works as expected. I'd appreciate any ideas or additional troubleshooting steps I could try.

EDIT:
The last statement that executes is a debug logging statement. When I commented out the `fmt.Printf` following it the program works as expected. Note: it's printing the same `[]byte` as the log statement above it.

```
    rsjson, err := json.Marshal(runSummary)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error().Err(err).Msgf("error marshaling RunSummary into string: %+v.\n")
        return
    }

    // TODO: debug stuff, only the printf should remain
    log.Info().Msgf("Run results: \n\n%s\n", rsjson)
    // TODO Removed Printf to see if it makes a difference
    // fmt.Printf("%s\n", string(rsjson))
    log.Info().Msgf("Run results COMPLETED")
```

Comment: My first guess would be that the code that prints "GracefulShutdown: Started" is somehow terminating the program.

Comment: I can't see where it might be doing that. It just calls a function that's used by the success path, logs that it completed (which doesn't appear in the output), and returns. I've put print logging in various places in that area and nothing prints after the initial `GracefulShutdown: Started` message. That said, I'll have another look. It makes as much sense as anything. Thanks!

Comment: The question does not include the code that's supposed to print the missing messages so we can only guess.

Comment: It also looks like you're using `time.Sleep` as a concurrency hack, which is a definite code smell. If you're relying on `Sleep` to make sure things are happening, your code has significant issues. You should be using channels, contexts, and wait groups to *know* when concurrent tasks have finished, not using `Sleep` to *hope* they've finished.

Comment: Agreed, the sleeps are definitely a code hack. They're there as kind of a "Hail Mary" to see if they somehow change the behavior of the code. They don't...

Answer (score 0):

I understand what I did wrong. It turns out the code is working. The command I was using though wasn't exactly what I put in the original question. If I run the command as originally posted above:

```
./runsomething
```

it works as expected when interrupted (`^C`).

But, the actual command pipes the output like this:

```
./runsomething | jq .
```

This exhibits the behavior described above, the output isn't printed. What fooled me is that the logging was going to stderr, so it looked like everything was working EXCEPT for the final `fmt.Printf`. Thinking about this a bit more, I'm cancelling the entire pipeline, i.e., `runsomething` and `jq`, not just `runsomething`. Doh!